# How can I validate the rotation transformation using imregister and imregtform for 2D images?

Tags: matlab, rotation, 2d, registration, transformation

I am trying to understand `imregtform`, I have rotated an image and then register it using `imregtform`, but the transformation matrix is totally different. I think this is because of the edges around the translated image, does anyone know how to validate the rotation results using `imregtform`?

```
tformSimilarity.T' = [17.0174   -1.0844 -771.0130  

                      1.0844    17.0174 -916.0525

                      0         0        1.0000]
```

My second question is about `imregister`. As far as I know imregister use `imwarp` which rotates an image from center and `imtransform` rotates it from (1,1) so it makes it more complicated if I use `imtransform` to create my known rotated image and then find the transformation using `imregister`?

```
M=100;N=M; 

A=zeros(M); 

A(1:M+1:50*(M+1))=1;

t=[ 0.8660 -0.5000 0; 0.5000 0.8660 0 ;0 0 1.0000];

figure; imshow(A);

B = imtransform(A, maketform('affine',t), 'XData', [1 N], 'YData', [1 M], 'Size', [M N]); 

fixed = A; 

moving = B; 

[optimizer,metric] = imregconfig('monomodal'); 

figure, 

imshowpair(A,B,'Scaling','joint'); 

tformSimilarity = imregtform(fixed,moving,'similarity',optimizer,metric);

tformSimilarity.T'
```